# How to pass method props via link next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-props

I have navbar component with sign in link that is linked to login page. I have handleLogin function in navbar component and I want pass it through the link and call it in login component.

How to pass this method? I tried using query and getServerSideProps but that's not working.

here is navbar component:

```
const Navbar = ({token}:{token:string|null}) => {
var [loggedIn,setLoggedIn]=false;
 const handleLogin=()=>{
    localStorage.removeItem("token")
    setLoggedIn(true)
   
   }
return (

    <>
      {
      
       loggedIn==true ? (
          
          <Link href={"#"}><a href="" onClick={handleLogOut} className="nav-link">log out <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser}/></a></Link>
        ):(
        //this is the link that I want it to pass handleLogin function
          <Link  href={{pathname:"/login",query:{handleLogin:handleLogin}}}><a href="" className="nav-link">Sign in <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser}/></a></Link>
        )
      }
</>
)
}
```

and this is the login page:

```
const Login = ({handleLogin}:{handleLogin:(...args:any[])=>void}) {

const [errors, setErrors] = useState([])
const validate=async()=>{
  try{
    const validateResult= await schema.validate(user,{abortEarly:false})
    setErrors([])
   return true
  
  }
 
  catch(er:any){
        console.log(er.errors)
         //@ts-ignore
        setErrors(er.errors)
        return false
  }
        
          
}

  const handleSubmit=async(e:React.SyntheticEvent)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const validateResult=await validate()
       if(validateResult==true){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user))
        try{
          const response=await axios.post(`https://reqres.in/api/login`,user)
          console.log(response.data)
          const token=response.data.token;
          localStorage.setItem("token",token)
          handleLogin()
        }
        catch(er){
          //@ts-ignore
        setErrors(["The username or password is incorrect"])
        localStorage.setItem("token","")
        }
       
       
       }
    
        
     }


     const handleChange=(e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
        setUser({...user,[e.currentTarget.id]:e.currentTarget.value})
     }

}


 return (
  <>
   <h5>to see the successfull login use:
    email:eve.holt@reqres.in,
    password:"cityslicka"
  </h5>
  <div className="wrapper fadeInDown">
   
     
    
  <div id="formContent">
    {errors.length!=0 && (
       <div className="vali">
       {errors.map((el:any)=>{
          
             return <>
                      
                       <div key={el.id} className="error-list">
                       {el}
                       </div>
                      
                      
                 
             
             </>
           })}
            </div>
    )}
 

 
    <div className="fadeIn first">
      Login
    </div>

  
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    
    <div className="form-floating form-outline">
      <input type="text"  id="email" className="fadeIn second form-control" placeholder='Mobile Phone' onChange={handleChange} />
      <label className="form-label" htmlFor="email">Email</label>
     </div>  
     <div className="form-floating form-outline">
      <input type="password"  id="password" className="fadeIn second form-control" placeholder='Password' onChange={handleChange}/>
      <label className="form-label" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
     </div>
     
      <input type="submit" className="fadeIn fourth "  value="Log In"/>
      
    </form>

    
    <div id="formFooter">
      <a className="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



  </>
  )

export const getServerSideProps = async(context:any) => {
  console.log(context.query) 
 
  

 
  return {
      props: { 
         handleLogin: context.query.handleLogin //pass it to the page props
      }
  }
}
export default Login;
```

When I try my code I see this error:

> 

Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | readonly string[] | readonly number[] | readonly boolean[] | null | undefined'.

> 

Comment: As the error mentions, you can't pass a function as a query param in `Link`.

Comment: @juliomalves oh no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant pass methods and functions via `Link`.

Now, you can use a contexts to share methods/functions/props between pages.

Moreover, if you want to keep some kind of props you can use window storage / cookie.

Comment: @tnx I used localstorage in my code(as you see above) to set token . but when i try to use localstorage(token) to another component(navbar), It delayed in changing state and I should refresh the page to see the changes. so i have to change state(loggedIn) directy after login!

Comment: using context was good idea and worked for me tnx!